# How to use bind "<Return>" to call a function

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I know my question sounds very much like many previous questions but I can honestly not figure it out in the context of my program. I have an algorithm for the Collatz Conjecture that I would like to run through a Tkinter GUI (everything works just fine through the terminal).I have tried to bind the relevant function to the Return key and to a button but I get the same error message for both methods of entering data, which I will show below. I get the output to work perfectly on the GUI if I input through the terminal.

What I have tried is best explained through the code below. (The code above the #### line has mostly to do with making the GUI appear over my Spyder IDE and not hiding behind it.)

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

import os
import subprocess
import platform

def raise_app(root: Tk):
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
        tmpl = 'tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of every process whose unix id is {} to true'
        script = tmpl.format(os.getpid())
        output = subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/osascript', '-e', script])
    root.after(0, lambda: root.attributes("-topmost", False))
########################################################################

lst = []

def collatz(num):
    while num != 1:
        lst.append(num)

        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = int(num / 2)

        else:
            num = int(3 * num + 1)

def main(event):

    collatz(num)

#Input Box
input = Entry(root, width = 10, bg = "light grey")
input.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
input.get()
input.bind("<Return>", main)

##Button
#button1 = Button(root, width = 10, text = "Run", command = main)
#button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

##Output box
output1 = Text(root, width = 100, height = 10, bg = "light grey")
output1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
output2 = Text(root, width = 50, height = 1, bg = "white")
output2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

output1.insert(END, lst)
output2.insert(END, "Number of iterations are: " + str(len(lst)))


########################################################################

raise_app(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run the code as is, the input box appears but when I click return, I get an error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/andrehuman/Desktop/Python/programs/Collatz Conjecture/Collatz_alt3.py", line 43, in main
    collatz(num)
NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

Exactly the same if I try and link a button to the "main" function.

When I comment the input and buttons out, and enter the number through the terminal, everything works as expected. The list of iteration numbers appear in the text box as it should. (And I can even get a Matplotlib graph to display the data visually in the terminal.) If I can get this problem sorted out I want to try and display (or embed) the Matplotlib graph in the GUI.

Anyway, that's it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Andre Human

Comment: So, you were expecting Python to magically know to call `int(input.get())` to supply a value for `num`?  You have certainly supplied no definition for `num` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`name 'num' is not defined` occurs because you're calling `collatz(num)`, but the program does not understand what value you are referring to when you say `num`. You should assign a value to that name before using it. I assume you want the value to be the contents of your `input` box.

```
def main(event):
    num = int(input.get())
    collatz(num)
```

You will also need to copy your `output1.insert` and `output2.insert` lines to the inside of `main`. Right now, those lines execute before the window even appears to the user, so there's no way that they can enter a number fast enough to get `collatz` to trigger before the text gets written. And changing `lst` after the fact does nothing to the text, since it's not smart enough to notice that the list has changed.

```
def main(event):
    num = int(input.get())
    collatz(num)
    #delete previous contents of text boxes
    output1.delete(1.0, END)
    output2.delete(1.0, END)
    output1.insert(END, lst)
    output2.insert(END, "Number of iterations are: " + str(len(lst)))
```

Another problem is that successive calls to `collatz` will cause `lst` to grow and grow, because the contents of the list from previous calls is still present. Try entering `4` into the text box, and press Enter a few times. The output will go from 2 to 4 to 6... That's not right.

This is something of a natural hazard when using mutable global state. One possible solution is to reset `lst` at the beginning of each collatz call.

```
def collatz(num):
    lst.clear()
    #rest of function goes here
```

... But I'm more inclined to make `lst` local to the function, and return it at the end.

```
def collatz(num):
    lst = []
    while num != 1:
        lst.append(num)

        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = int(num / 2)

        else:
            num = int(3 * num + 1)
    return lst

def main(event):
    num = int(input.get())
    lst = collatz(num)
    #delete previous contents of text boxes
    output1.delete(1.0, END)
    output2.delete(1.0, END)
    output1.insert(END, lst)
    output2.insert(END, "Number of iterations are: " + str(len(lst)))

#later, just before mainloop is called...
#lst doesn't exist in this scope, so just set the text to a literal value
output1.insert(END, "[]")
output2.insert(END, "Number of iterations are: 0")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help, Kevin. (I'm just starting to find my way around programming and its purely a hobby anyway.) With this code and your explanations I will be able to tackle similar things easily. Andre